# When I try to create an LI element for my todo-list app, nothing shows up on my browser screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, user-input

I have been working on this todo-list app in JavaScript and have tried a couple different approaches but I am having trouble getting my list to display on the screen. I have tried initializing an empty array and pushing the input.value into the array in my function and console.logging the array, which works but only shows the current value I typed in, instead of saving all values. So my question is, why is my function not adding list elements to the screen, and part 2, how to get every element in the array shown if I were to use an empty array.
I am a beginner to JavaScript and have looked at many pages about user input and `document.getElementById` on Stack Overflow, but I was hoping someone could help explain why my code is not running.

My HTML:

```js
//This is my code for trying to add li and get it to display on screen:
//when I run this in the browser, there are no errors, but also nothing happens.

function newTodo() {

  var input = document.getElementById("todo-text").value;
  const list = document.getElementById("todo-list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("- " + input));
  list.appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";

}
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    newTodo();
  }
};
// Editor Note: Commenting this code out since it defines the same function name
/*
//Option 2 I have tried:

//JavaScript array todo:

window.onload = function() {
  const button = document.getElementById('btn');
  button.addEventListener("click", newTodo, false);
}
let todoItems = [];


//prints element on console when typed, but when I try to add a new element the page refreshes with a new array instead of adding to same array

function newTodo() {
  input = document.getElementById('todo-text');
  todoItems.push(input.value);
  input.value = "";

  console.log(todoItems);


}
*/
```

```html
<form class="add-todo">
  <input type="text" id="todo-text" name="newTodo">
  <button class="button center" id="btn">New TODO</button>

</form>
<ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Pressing Enter on a form submits the form by default.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function newTodo(evt) {

  evt.preventDefault();

  const input = document.getElementById("todo-text").value;
  const list = document.getElementById("todo-list");
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("- " + input));
  list.appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("todo-text").value = "";

}
    
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.getElementById("my-form").addEventListener("submit", newTodo, false);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form class="add-todo" id="my-form">
  <input type="text" id="todo-text" name="newTodo">

  </form>
  <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Sorry. Short on time and there was too much to explain

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand what the preventDefault was and I had played around with that but this is much more clear. Thank you!